Create file on AD samba share: Permission denied
I am setting up a samba active directory server (inside fmstrat docker container) on ubuntu server 22.04.
After some trial on error I achieved:

hosting an AD server on my ubuntu server
joining a windows client (win11)
joining two linux clients (ubuntu 23.04, 23.10)
joiing my NAS
sharing some directories from ubuntu server through volume mappings and host them in samba (smb.conf)

My problem is with the last step. I can:

access the share from windows AD client (read/write/create)
view the share from linux clients

But I am not able to create any new files on the samba share from linux client. I am completely stuck and going in circles. Hoping for some advice / pointers from this community. (if this is the wrong place, please tell me).
On ubuntu server I have a couple of directories I want to share (~/services/openhab/conf, ~/services/openhab/userdata).
On the same server, the samba docker container is running. The directories I want to share are volume mapped.
services:
  samba:
    image: nowsci/samba-domain
    container_name: samba
    volumes:
      - [some other volume mappings 
      - /home/localadmin/services/openhab/conf:/shares/openhab/conf
      - /home/localadmin/services/openhab/userdata:/shares/openhab/userdata

On the ubuntu server side, these files are owned by the openhab user (local account).
localadmin@dc:~/services/openhab$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  2 openhab           993 4096 Apr  6 18:35 addons
drwxrwxrwx 14 openhab           993 4096 Apr  7 10:37 conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 localadmin localadmin  590 Apr  6 18:30 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxrwx 11 openhab           993 4096 Apr  7 10:37 userdata

Inside the docker container, the files are owned by a numbered user and group (no clue who this is, I am guessing some default start index of AD users?)
root@dc:/# ls -l /shares/openhab/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 14 998 993 4096 Apr  7 10:37 conf
drwxrwxrwx 11 998 993 4096 Apr  7 10:37 userdata

And finally, in smb.conf, the shares are defined as follow:
[Openhab-conf]
        path = /shares/openhab/conf
        read only = no
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        force create mode = 0666
        force directory mode = 0777
        browseable = yes
        valid users = "@sb.lan\domain users"
        force group = "Domain Users"

[Openhab-userdata]
    path = /shares/openhab/userdata
        read only = no
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        force create mode = 0666
        force directory mode = 0777
        browseable = yes

When I mount the share from linux client which successfully joined the domain:
(in fstab)
//192.168.1.100/Openhab-conf        /media/openhab-conf     cifs  credentials=/home/bp@sb.lan/creds/ad.credentials,vers=2.0 0  0

I can see the share and list all files, but when I try to create a file in any folder inside the share, I get the following error:
bp@sb.lan@bas-hp:~$ touch /media/openhab-conf/scripts/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/media/openhab-conf/scripts/test.txt': Permission denied

When I ls -l on the mount:
bp@sb.lan@bas-hp:~$ ls -l /media/openhab-conf/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  6 20:35 automation
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 20:47 html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  6 20:30 icons
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 items
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 rules
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 services
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 sitemaps
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 sounds
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 tags
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 things
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 apr  7 12:37 transform
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92 apr  7 12:37 workspace.code-workspace

I can see these files are owned by root/root. I can sudo chown -R bp@sb.lan /media/openhab-conf but this doesn't affect the ownership shown by ls -l.
Again, the shares works perfectly fine on a windows machine which has joined the same AD.
I have no clue what the problem is. I am guessing on linux side since I can access the share without issues from windows client. So that suggests to me that ubuntu server => samba docker is working fine. But on the other hand, I tried to overrule all permissions on linux side to no avail....
Any advise would be greatly appreciated!
